# Chats list withdraw logic

Tags: php, algorithm

There is a website. I am storing chats of the user as single json files for each chat. So when user request chat list, php script reads directory where chats stored and returns array of chats. Array is sorted by last message date.

Obviously, I need not to withdraw chats, but per-page: first 10 chats, then next 10 chats. But chats are every time sorted, that is confusing me.

How do I make per-page withdraw for other, simpler lists:

There also is a products catalog (it is a shop).

Consider an array of json objects with “id” field each. When in frontend user requests first page, server returns first 10 elements of array. Frontend stores last element’s id.

Then, when second page need to be loaded fronted calls the same request, but now also passing last element id. Now server will not return elements from 0 to 10, but from id->index + 1 to id->index + 11.

How to do that with chats array, where order is always changing?

```
 // example of catalog items withdraw

 $a = json_decode(‘[{“id”:1640}, {“id”:5292},{“id”:3720}]’, true); // order is constant
 $last = ‘’;
 $ok = true;

 if(isset($_GET[“last”]))
 {
     $last = $_GET[“last”];
     $ok = false;
 }

 $ret = [];

 for($i = 0; $i < count($a) && count($ret) < 10; $i++)
    if(!$ok && $a[$i][“i”] == $last)
       $ok = true;
    else
       $ret[count($ret)] = $a[$i];

 echo json_encode($ret);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I currently imagine is the next:

Instead of case from my question, where server returns elements in range from specified as argument element to next 10 elements, i.e. (specified, specified+10], in case of chats it needs to be returned always from first to specified page, not element.

By default method returns elements [0, 10). When in frontend user scrolls chats list down, client will make same request but passing `page=2` as an argument, and server will return elements [0, 20) and so on.

So, yes, in case reaching about 30th page there probably will be troubles, but, yet initially the problem with overloading is solved, because only first 10, then first 20 and so on elements will be passed and rendered.

```
if(isset($_GET["chats"]) && isset($_GET["page"]))
{
// Initialize, get user data, get array of chats
$a = json_decode(‘[{}, {}, {}]’, true); // An array of already sorted by last message date chats

$result = [];
$page = intval($_GET[“page”]);
if(!$page)
  $page = 1;

$max = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < count($a) && $i < $page * $max; $i++)
  $result[$i] = $a[$i];

echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```